# How to filter or search the posts using postmeta tables custom meta fields with wordpress REST API

Tags: custom-field, wp-api, rest-api

I'm new to wordpress and also working with WP REST API for mobile application development for the wordpress website. Here I want get data's filter & search based post meta custom fields.

I've tried for this example but getting all results not belongs property_featured=1

Kindly find my postmeta table structure for example.

```
meta id post id meta key           meta value 
---------------------------------------------
2548    1000    property_featured    
3068    1078    property_featured   1   
3619    1124    property_featured   1
```

Here i want to get the post based on property_featured=1 only. Pls help to me fix on this.

Comment: This is a simple SQL query, you may do it using WP_query. If you're not familiar with SQL, you may find many examples of WP_query... After that, it depends what your parameters are (static, comming from user...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add custom query vars:

```
add_filter('rest_query_vars', 'wpse225850_add_rest_query_vars');

function wpse225850_add_rest_query_vars($query_vars) {

    $query_vars = array_merge( $query_vars, array('meta_key', 'meta_value', 'meta_compare') );

    return $query_vars;

}
```

Now, get your posts at `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[meta_key]=property_featured&filter[meta_value]=1`.

You can follow [this ticket](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1599#issuecomment-161166805) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to know which file need to add given above code. Is it possible to do multiple custom meta fields like above mentioned answer.

Comment: Anyone pls help to me which file i need to add given answer.

Comment: in your wordpress plugin

Comment: @shankarmsr Add the code to your `functions.php` file.

Comment: @Dan Its works fine. But if the meta value was empty means that post also returning with response so this case empty field post are not able to come right. And also is it possible to get filter works for multiple custome fields here

Comment: @shankarmsr 1. If meta value is empty, empty array will be returned.  2. Yes, you can. Just append each query with `&filter[meta_key]=key&filter[meta_value]=value`.  You should take a look at [official docs](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/)

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your info. I have one doubt,how to filter the data's for based on conditions like greater or less than & between. Example I need to get the data's where price between and greater or less than. Help me to  solve this.

Comment: @shankarmsr you should make another question.

Comment: @Dan okay fine. I'll ask another question. And more doubt is there any possibilities filter the data's using postmeta fields(custom fields) & terms taxonomy(custom categories) with combination here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39430/discussion-between-shankar-msr-and-dan).

Comment: Keep in mind that this will expose all your meta fields for filtering. In some cases you might not want that!